# making a loop with jquery, Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to make a loop in jquery, Ajax and PHP.

my pages are:
`shop.php`
`do_ajax.php`

in the `shop.php` are variable `$p_productid` is `1` and `$j_productid` is `$p_productid`

```
var j_productid = <?= $p_productid ?>;
```

now i do `j_productid++` so the output from `$j_productid` is `2`
now i'm posting this with ajax to `do_ajax.php`

in the `do_ajax.php` are variable `$pa_productid` is `$_POST['$j_productid']`;

now i can place this on html, but i want to set this value in too the variable on `$p_productid` on `shop.php`

how i need to do this?

there is working a swipe system in this case so only with php it isnt working i need to work with jquery that's why am i doing this on this way. i got an another solution without AJAX but i want that you cant see on the client side the webpage is refreshing.

`JQUERY`

```
wipeLeft: function() {
    var j_ProductId = <?= $g_ProductId ?>;
    var j_Swiped = 1;
    if (j_ProductId < <?= $l_LastProduct ?>){
        j_ProductId++
        //document.swiping.productid.value = j_ProductId;
        //document.swiping.submit();
        $.ajax({
                url: 'do_ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { swipe : j_Swiped,
                        productid : j_ProductId},
                success: function (data) {
                     $('.product').html(data);
                }
        });
    }

}
```

`do_ajax.php`

```
if(!empty($_POST['swipe'])){
    $l_ProductId = $_POST['productid'];
    echo $l_ProductId;
}
```

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Did you just created the same question as this one by yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719030/jquery-to-ajax-to-php-file?noredirect=1#comment45725193_28719030 ?

Comment: @bcesars yeah thats the same question but here i explain it better then there. and the answers what i get there didn't work for me.

Comment: Well... just close other question then and keep with this one. =)

Comment: @bcesars how can i close it? :o

Comment: Well²... I think you don't have enought rep to do this... LOL. Try to flag it.

Comment: You should `echo` your php variables in your jquery code and quote it, like:
`var j_ProductId = '<?php echo $g_ProductId ?>';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the JavaScript (even if generated dynamically by PHP) is not running the same time that PHP is running. Your workflow will be something like this:

1. PHP script (shop.php) is invoked
2. PHP script generates output, HTML and JS mixed.
3. These are all in server side until the web server sends the output to client (browser)
4. In browser HTML displays and JS runs with starting values that you generated previously by PHP. But in this time, PHP has been finished, not running anymore. PHP variables are not alive anymore.
5. JS interacts with the user in browser, we can say it's running continuously.
6. Triggered by an action (swipe) JS sends an (ajax) request from client side to server side. This request transfers the new value to server side, and invokes another PHP script (do_ajax.php). You do whatever you want with the new value (process it and or store it) in server side. You need to understand that you are in a completely disjunct scope in PHP than in your first PHP script. (distinct in time too)
7. If you want to be sure that, in case of a page reload, the (product ID) value will be the updated value, you need to store it somewhere (user session, key-value store, database, or any persistent) when you get it in server side (so in do_ajax.php) and later load this value in the beginning of your shop.php script ...which will pass it to the JS, and so on. The workflow starts again.